# Where to place Twitter Bootstrap Files in a maven project?

Tags: maven, twitter-bootstrap

I starting out to create something using Twitter Bootstrap & Spring MVC. Can someone tell me where to place the Bootstrap CSS/JS/HTML files in a maven project structure?

My JSP page shows up fine. But, it's not able to get a hold on the CSS & JS files.

```
<link href="..resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../resources/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "src/main/resources" folder is for resources that get copied and integrated with the compiled Java code in the resulting artifact (in this case, the WAR under "WEB-INF/classes").

The "src/main/webapp" folder represents the root of your web content.  You'll need to add those web content resources there for them to be available to the JSP(s).

Answer (score 24):

You could use [Web Jars](http://www.webjars.org/) to bring them in as a Maven dependency. This gives you all the benefits of the Maven dependency management. The documentation page details how to use the resources in your app.

Comment: Would you explain how to refer to bootstrap library in jsp in case when using maven dependency ?

Comment: @Mark There are several examples in the [documentation] (http://www.webjars.org/documentation)